# type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function in custom react component

Tags: antd

I have an antd table with 2 columns which I need to filter on the first, and search text on the second column.

If I remove the line:   ...this.getColumnSearchProps('Tags'),

from my code, the application is rendered fine.  Please note the tags field is a json array, not a text field, so I guess that has something to do  with the error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Table, Tag, Button, Icon, Input} from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';
import Highlighter from 'react-highlight-words';

class ListPageTemplatesWithSelection extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            filteredInfo: null,
            sortedInfo: null,
            searchText: ''
        };
        this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.clearFilters= this.clearFilters.bind(this);
        this.clearAll= this.clearAll.bind(this);
        this.getColumnSearchProps= this.getColumnSearchProps.bind(this);
        this.handleSearch= this.handleSearch.bind(this);
        this.handleReset= this.handleReset.bind(this);

    }

    handleSearch (selectedKeys, confirm){
      confirm();
      this.setState({ searchText: selectedKeys[0] });
    }

    handleReset(clearFilters){
      clearFilters();
      this.setState({ searchText: '' });
    }

    getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex) => ({
        filterDropdown: ({
        setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters,
      }) => (
        <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
          <Input
            ref={node => { this.searchInput = node; }}
            placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
            value={selectedKeys[0]}
            onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
            onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
            style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
          />
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
            icon="search"
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90, marginRight: 8 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Reset
          </Button>
        </div>
      ),
      filterIcon: filtered => <Icon type="search" style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
      onFilter: (value, record) => record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
      onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
        if (visible) {
          setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select());
        }
      },
      render: (text) => (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text.toString()}
        />
      ),
    })

    handleChange(pagination, filters, sorter){
      console.log('Various parameters', pagination, filters, sorter);
      this.setState({
        filteredInfo: filters,
        sortedInfo: sorter,
      });
    }

    clearFilters(){
      this.setState({ filteredInfo: null });
    }

    clearAll(){
      this.setState({
        filteredInfo: null,
        sortedInfo: null,
      });
    }

    fetchData = () => {
        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/PageTemplates", {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            if (!this.isCancelled) {
                const results= responseJson.map(row => ({
                    key: row.Id,
                    Name: row.Name,
                    SiteType: row.SiteType,
                    Tags: row.Tags
                  }))
              this.setState({ data: results });
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };


    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render(){
          let { sortedInfo, filteredInfo } = this.state;
        sortedInfo = sortedInfo || {};
        filteredInfo = filteredInfo || {};

        const columns = [
                {
                    title: 'Id',
                    dataIndex: 'key',
                    key: 'key',
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                    key: 'Name',
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Site Type',
                    dataIndex: 'SiteType',
                    key: 'SiteType',
                    filters: [
                      { text: 'Modern Team Site', value: 'Modern Team Site' },
                      { text: 'CommunicationSite', value: 'CommunicationSite' },
                    ],
                    filteredValue: filteredInfo.SiteType || null,
                    onFilter: (value, record) => record.SiteType.includes(value),
                },{
                  title: 'Tags',
                  key: 'Tags',
                  dataIndex: 'Tags',
                  ...this.getColumnSearchProps('Tags'),
                  render: Tags => (
                    <span>
                    {Tags && Tags.map(tag => {
                      let color = tag.length > 5 ? 'geekblue' : 'green';
                      if (tag === 'loser') {
                        color = 'volcano';
                      }
                      return <Tag color={color} key={tag}>{tag.toUpperCase()}</Tag>;
                    })}
                  </span>)

                }
        ];

        const rowSelection = {
            selectedRowKeys: this.props.selectedRows,
            onChange: (selectedRowKeys) => {
              this.props.onRowSelect(selectedRowKeys);
            }
          };


        return (
          <div>
            <Button onClick={this.clearFilters}>Clear filters</Button>
            <Button onClick={this.clearAll}>Clear filters and sorters</Button>
            <Table rowSelection={rowSelection}  columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ListPageTemplatesWithSelection;
```

However with that line, the application stops rendering and I got multiple errors like this:

Error on interface:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
▶ 23 stack frames were collapsed.
AsyncFunc._callee$
src/helpers/AsyncFunc.js:26
  23 | const { default: Component } = await importComponent();
  24 | Nprogress.done();
  25 | if (this.mounted) {
> 26 |   this.setState({
  27 |     component: <Component {...this.props} />
  28 |   });
  29 | }
```

what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Maybe it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969557/querying-azure-web-apps-version-number?rq=1

Comment: `getColumnSearchProps` returns `Function`, not object, right? So obviously, you can't spread the result. Also, `bind` arrow function doesn't do anything, you can remove binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the current version to the front-end somehow. Is it metadata that can be retrieved from your azure pipeline? Do you perhaps have pre or postbuild scripts? These could update a variable (++) in a database that you could either retrieve from the front-end with an ajax call or send along when downloading the Js bundle from your server.

When you have retrieved the data somewhere somehow in your back-end, you may also consider passing the version number as a header in the http response.

Comment: For anyone thinking about a downvote: This answer was posted when the question had a completely different content.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Different content, different title.